# Hermite rank of an $L^2$ function

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, time-series

Let $(H_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be the sequence of hermite polynimials, $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and $G\in L^2(\mathbb{R},\phi)$ with $\operatorname{E}\left[Z\right]=0$. By $\phi$ we denote the density of the standard normal distribution. Than exists a unique representation
\begin{align}
G(Z)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{J(k)}{k!}H_k(Z)
\end{align}
in $L^2(\Omega)$ where
\begin{align}
J(k):=\operatorname{E}\left[G(Z)H_k(Z)\right].
\end{align} We call
\begin{align}
m:=\min_{k\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq1}}\operatorname{E}\left[G(Z)H_k(Z)\right]\neq 0\}
\end{align}
the hermite rank of $G$.

Assume now that the hermite rank of $G$ is 1. Is the hermite rank of 
\begin{align*}
1\{G(x)\leq u\} \text{   for fixed $u\in\mathbb{R}$}
\end{align*}
also 1? I.e. is $\operatorname{E}\left[1\{G(Z)\leq u\}H_1(Z)\right]= \operatorname{E}\left[1\{G(Z)\leq u\}Z\right]\neq 0$?

Comment: Let's choose $G(x):=1\{x>0\}$, i.e. $G\in L^2(\mathbb{R},\phi)$. It follows that 
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{E}\left[ 1\{  1\{Z>0\}\leq u\} Z\right]= \int_{\{1\{Z>0\}\leq u\}} Z  d \Phi,
\end{align*}but for all $u<0$ is $\{1\{Z>0\}\leq u\}=\emptyset$. Therefore is 
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{E}\left[1\{G(Z)\leq u\}Z\right]= 0
\end{align*} for all $u<0$. Therefore depends the hermite rank of $G$ in general on $u\in\mathbb{R}$. Does anybody see a mistake in my argumentation? Thanks!